# How to create a form where one dropdown determines options of another

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, forms, alpacajs

I need to create a form with 3 dropdown fields, where each dropdown should populate with options based on the selection of the previous one. I have all my data in an object.

For example:

```js
{
  "campaign1": {
    "name": "Campaign 1",
    "projects": {
      "job A": [
        "proj 1"
      ],
      "job B": [
        "proj 2",
        "proj 3"
      ]
    }
  },
  "campaign2": {
    "name": "Campaign 2",
    "projects": {
      "job C": [
        "proj 4",
        "proj 5",
        "proj 6"
      ],
      "job D": [
        "proj 7",
        "proj 8",
        "proj 9"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is that first you choose a "Campaign", then the 2nd dropdown shows only the "Jobs" for that campaign, then the 3rd shows only the "Projects" for that job.

I started with https://github.com/json-editor/json-editor but it doesn't seem able to do what I need. I looked at alpaca also, but it's daunting.

Alpaca has an `optiontree` field type but that doesn't seem to do what I want (in that I'm not assigning 'attributes' to a 'value') although the rendered version *behaves* the way I want.

I would like to use my data object as is, although I can re-structure it if necessary.

Basically I want something like the driver chooser on nvidia ...
https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx
First pick a type, then a series based on the type, etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the structure of the object for my convenience. It makes the implementation easier. use the index value as value attribute in option tag which can be used in retrieve the child object for next filter. I made a sample code for second filter based on the result of campaign filter.

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
   var selected_index = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
   var selected_val = $(this).children("option:selected").html();
   var obj = [{
     "Campaign 1": {
     "name": "Campaign 1",
        "jobs": [{
            "name" : "job A",
            "projects": [
               "proj 1"
             ]},{
            "name" : "job B",  
            "projects": [
                "proj 2",
                "proj 3"
             ]}
         ]}
       },{
     "Campaign 2": {
          "name": "Campaign 2",
          "jobs": [{
               "name" : "job C",
               "projects": [
                   "proj 4",
                   "proj 5",
                   "proj 6"
               ]},{
               "name" : "job D",
               "projects": [
                   "proj 7",
                   "proj 8",
                   "proj 9"
               ]}
           ]}
       }];
   jQuery('#select_2').html('');
   obj[selected_index[selected_val].jobs.forEach( function(data, index){
     jQuery('#select_2').append('<option value="index">data</option>');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option you could use to the replace the data source for each field, depending on the previous selection. Here is a working JS Fiddle where the dropdown options are determined by the previous selection: https://jsfiddle.net/bsunderland/78hybL3v/3/

Also, here is some sample code for setting the options in a select based on a previous field selection, but with a server side call:

```
"postRender": function(control) {
            var parentType = control.childrenByPropertyId["Parent_LookupTypeCode"]; //Grab the Parent Lookup Type Object
            var parentCode = control.childrenByPropertyId["Parent_LookupCode"]; //Grab the Parent Lookup Object
            parentCode.subscribe(parentType, function(val) {//Subscribe parentCode to changes to parentType
                // alert(val);
                if(!val) {//val = value of parentType
                    val="Metrics"; //If missing, do nothing
                }
                else{
                    this.options.dataSource = "./ExtraStuff/Load_Lookups.php?q=" + val; //Load values based on val of parentType
                }

                this.refresh(); //Refresh the form. This is needed. Without it, the updated options won't show
            });
        }
```